What is a night equivalent for words referring to day parts?
I'm looking for exact equivalents for words like Morning, Afternoon, and Evening. I'm on a graveyard shift and I dislike specifying the actual hour, plus it makes greetings weird. Currently I just use Nightfall, Midnight, and Night's End, then refer to day as just day (inversion of regular day vocab, where night is referred to as just night)
I know the exact words I'm looking for probably don't exist so if they don't, how would I modify the etymology of the pre-existing terms for day parts to refer to night?
I'll accept non-English words too since English borrows from so many languages already, but I'd prefer ones accepted as English. If this question has already been asked, I couldn't find it but would appreciate a link, and if I need to edit this let me know as it's my first time posting on stackexchange.

What does "modify the etymology" mean? The past is already written. A word's etymon (or etyma) cannot be retroactively replaced, such as by switching an Ancient Greek root to a medieval Russian one.

Where I'm from the words morning, afternoon, evening and night divide the day exactly in 6 hour blocks. night 0-6, morning 6-12, afternoon 12-18, evening 18-24. But I'm aware that that is not true everywhere

You could borrow from the nautical watch system: mid = 0000 - 0400, morning = 0400 - 0800, forenoon = 0800 - 1200, etc. You get to explain what the two dog watches are, for extra fun.

There are no "exact equivalent" words in English, unfortunately. (For anything.)

@tchrist I think they're talking about deriving new words from the same sources. Say for example, "after+noon" → "after+midnight" or "before+midnight"

There are some direct correlations, but other words have no direct opposite.

Dusk - the part where the sun still has some effect in lighting.  So this moves around the clock depending on time of year and latitude.
Evening - 18:00~22:00 regardless of sunlight.  Opposite to Morning
Midnight - anything near 00:00. Opposite to Noon or "Lunch time"
The Witching Hour - A window of about an hour after midnight.  Probably lines up with "Siesta"
Small or Tiny or Wee Hours - approximately 02:00 to 05:00 where the clock "moves faster" and therefor hours are shorter because most of the population is asleep then.   Arguablly this opposes Afternoon. Commenteers also added that another reason for the name is the ordinal single digits themselves are small, hence the diminutive
Dawn or first light - where the sun starts having an impact on light levels.  Opposite to Dusk.
Sunrise - when the sun's disk is first visible over the horizon.

"Graveyard shift" implies a longer window, approximately an 8 hour period, so might go from 22:00 to 06:00.
"Morning shift" would then take over and go to 14:00 or a little later.
"Evening shift" fills in the remaining time between 14:00 and 22:00
Some 24-hour outfits run overlapping shifts with a higher staffing level at busy times, so there may be "early/late dinner" shifts, to suit the needs of the business.

Interesting explanation of "Small or Tiny or Wee Hours" - I always though it was because 1, 2, 3 are wee numbers (as opposed to e.g. 10, 11, 12).

The wee hours are also often called "late night", although in TV schedules that usually refers to 11pm-2am, when the late night talk shows air.

According to the OED, the small hours are co-called because the numbers are small, as @ReversedEngineer says above.

Point 5 here is totally wrong.  the wee hours are because the numbers are the digits 1, 2.

Y'all are welcome to edit this post - I'd never heard of Wee hours being related to the cardinality.  Certainly plausible, so I added it.

@Criggie Apparently it is that; Etymology Online says: "Wee hours ... so called for their low numbers." But I believed your explanation before I read the comments :)

What you're calling "dawn" is actually sunrise and what you're calling "pre-dawn" is actually dawn. Dawn is twilight in the morning, the opposite of dusk, which is twilight at night. I don't think I've heard "pre-dawn" before, but I guess it'd still be dark then.

@wjandrea I approved the edit after it had been rejected by the review queue - not sure how that shows up for you, but it went in.

Also - converted to Community Wiki now.
